# Can I connect 14 gauge wire to 12 gauge wire

Tags: electrical

I have an existing ceiling fan with no light that has 12/2 wire in box which is ran to a single switch that is also wired with 12/2. Want to change out fan with newer model that includes a light kit. Also want to take single switch and make a two gang, switch for light and switch for fan. So my question is when I remove the existing 12/2 switch leg, can I run 14/3 from switch to fan? Or do I need to run 12/3?

Comment: What size is the breaker?  If _any_ 14ga wire is used, it must be a 15A breaker.

Comment: Currently a 20A breaker. So If changed to a 15A then 14g wire will work for switch leg

Comment: Yes, correct. `14ga needs max. 15A breaker.

Comment: Why not just use 12/3 tho and keep the 20A circuit?

Comment: @Keyros - until the next guy (or you if you forget) wonder why on earth some idiot put a 15A breaker on 12g wire (because they only look at what's connected in the panel and don't follow every last foot of wiring in the walls) and switch it back to a 20A breaker ... Rather use 12/3 and stay safe & consistent.

Comment: Cost savings of using 14/3 instead of 12/3 will be lost when you have to buy a 15a breaker in order to use the cheaper 14/3! Even if you already have the materials on hand, consider that you may not know every inch of the circuit. Maybe there's something else on it that needs the 20a breaker. Also @brhans makes a great point about future-proofing this by just keeping it 12 gauge and 20a.

Answer (score 8):

#### Depends on the Breaker

The breaker protects the devices but also protects the wiring. Too much current heats up the wires in the walls --> fire! You have two likely possibilities:

- 15A Breaker

14 AWG wire is rated for 15A of current. If the circuit is already on a 15A breaker then you can go ahead and swap any or all of the 12 AWG wiring for 14 AWG without any problems.

- 20A Breaker

12 AWG wire is rated for 20A of current. If the circuit is currently on a 20A breaker then you can't have 14 AWG wire in the circuit. You can either continue to use 12 AWG wire everywhere **or** you can replace the 20A breaker with a 15A breaker. However, if you replace the breaker then you may want to mark it in the panel because the next person might see 12 AWG wire connected and think that it could be replaced with a 20A breaker.

Keep in mind that a 20A breaker (and matching wire) can be very useful **even if you don't have any individual devices that need 20A**. For example, if you have a 15A circuit and someone plugs in a heating device (hair dryer, portable heater, toaster oven, etc.) it will typically draw ~ 12A = 1,440 watts while in use. That leaves only ~ 3A to spare for all lights, fans, TVs, computers, etc. that share the circuit. With a 20A circuit, you have 7A to spare, which can make the difference between having nuisance trips (or avoidance of usage) or not.